# "Noisy Tabs" in Google Chrome- Detecting if sound is playing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Google Chrome recently introduced the feature that allows users to tell what tab is making that ["Noisy sound"](http://chrome.blogspot.com/2014/01/everyone-can-now-track-down-noisy-tabs.html). What i'm interested in finding out is if this new feature allows `chrome extensions` to detect if a tab is making a sound.

There is no documentation of any similar feature on the [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) developer page. Is there a way that you would be able to detect if a sound is playing (Without taking a "guess" based off of the content of the page i.e if the page contains `mp3` or video content)

Comment: look ath this: http://beta.slashdot.org/story/155604

Comment: @Thouartamazing - this won't work because those aren't the only thing that can generate and play audio. We have to wait for Google to release an api for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

necromancer here ...

It's now possible in Chrome 45 :
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs

boolean (optional) audible
Since Chrome 45. Warning: this is the current Beta channel. Learn more.

Whether the tab has produced sound over the past couple of seconds